# Make @ features in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wanting to make a module in python that includes @ 'commands', I'm thinking something along the lines of the click library such as this `@click.command()`. I'm just unsure if I would use a class or something else for this.

I've tried using classes, but those seem to behave differently than an @ command.

Comment: Do you mean decorators?

Comment: Yes, I did not know that is what they were called, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a decorator, you need to have a callable that takes a single argument.

For example:

```
def trivial_decorator(f):
    return f
```

You can now use it like this:

```
@trivial_decorator
def my_function():
    print('hi')
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
def my_function():
    print('hi')

my_function = trivial_decorator(my_function)
```

It doesn't do anything useful yet, of course.

Suppose you want to keep track of a list of functions, you could do this:

```
FUNCTION_REGISTRY = []

def register(func):
    FUNCTION_REGISTRY.append(func)
    return func
```

Now you could add `@register` in front of all functions you want to register.

Or maybe you want to do something with the arguments or return values of a function.

Let's say you want to be able to write a function that adds two numbers together but call it like `add('5', '10')` to get `15`.

You could do something like this:

```
def intify_args(func):
    def second_func(arg1, arg2):
        return func(int(arg1), int(arg2))
    return second_func

@intify_args
def add(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2
```

Now you return a different function in your decorator. That works, but if you try to do something like `help(add)`, you'll notice that Python thinks the function should be called `second_func` instead of `add`. To fix that, Python actually has a decorator called [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) that updates the documentation of a function, so you could do something like:

```
import functools

def intify_args(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def second_func(arg1, arg2):
        return func(int(arg1), int(arg2))
    return second_func
```

Decorators are an amazingly handy tool to have in your mental toolbox, I almost always have some place where a decorator really simplifies my code. A favourite of mine (which I think should be in the standard library, to be honest), is this one:

```
def join(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        return ''.join(map(str, f(*args, **kwargs)))
    return _
```

Which allows you to construct string builder functions, like so:

```
@join
def make_some_string(one, two):
    yield '('
    yield frobnicate(one)
    yield from blorbo(two)
    yield ')'

# call it like make_some_string(1, 2) to get a string that is all those elements joined together
```

They can be a bit tricky to get your head around at first, but I suggest looking at the source code of decorators like `functools.wraps` and `click.command` to get a feel for them.